# Как понимать требования закона?

Tags: пунктуация, синонимы

В законе устанавливаются дополнительные требования, дословно:
*наличие высшего юридического или экономического образования либо образования по специальности, соответствующей сфере деятельности должника.*,

"или" и "либо" - синонимы, тогда идет перечисление и должны стоять запятые перед "или" и "либо". Но если их нет, то надо ли понимать, что имеется 2 варианта дополнительных требований:

- 1 вариант: юридическое или экономическое
- 2 вариант: образование по специальности

или все же имеется ввиду три варианта:

- 1 вариант: юридическое
- 2 вариант:экономическое
- 3 вариант: образование по специальности?

***Правка к вопросу*** [[@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0)](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0), я не прошу объяснить смысл требований к управляющему, установленные  законом о банкротстве. С точки зрения русского языка Вы тоже склоняетесь, что правилен как первый вариант, так и второй. Но нужно разобраться, как все же читать правильно, поскольку это имеет принципиальное значение.Установят дополнительное требование в виде высшего юридического образования, значит человек имеющий экономическое не сможет стать управляющим. А если прочитать закон как имеющий два варианта дополнительных требований: юридическое или экономическое, а 2 вариант, чтобы имел образование по специальности, то человека с высшим экономическим не могут ограничить таким доптребованием.

Comment: >имеется 2 варианта... 1 вариант... 2 вариант... или ... три варианта: 1 вариант.. 2 вариант ...  3 вариант...   

Что-то я тут запутался с вариантами. Вы не могли бы *ваши* варианты понимания от вариантов *требований* как-то отделить?!

Comment: С точки зрения р. языка я ответила: запятых не должно быть ни в одном из вариантов, а с точки зрения логики так: конкурсной комиссии предоставляется право выбрать из двух вариантов: либо предъявить требование к кандидатуре арбитражного управляющего иметь юридическое или экономическое образование, либо требование иметь высшее специальное образование - такое же, как у должника.И если конкурсная комиссия предъявит первое требование,а у Вас будет экономическое обр-е, то Вам повезло, а если выберет второе, а должник ветеринар,то не повезло - предпочтение отдадут ветеринару с высшим образованием.

Comment: Людмила, с точки зрения русского претензий нет.
Вот с точки зрения логики - совершенно непонятно, о каких двух вариантах вы вообще говорите. Во-первых, из теста ничего такого не следует, насет должника, во-вторых, какое вообще может быть "образование" у должника юридического-лица? 
Но самое главное, в чем вообще разница между Вашими двумя вариантами? Да комиссия может выставить любой из них. А может еще и третий. Вообще не выставлять требований. Или четвертый. Юридическое или специальное, экономическое, дескать, не подходит. Почему нет, если исходить из текста?

Comment: Мне кажется, что мы совершенно напрасно пытаемся рассуждать с точки зрения того, кому "повезло". Субъектом права в данном случае является не кандидат на должность, а комиссия, давайте смотреть, какие требование она может выдвинуть согласно Закону, а какие нет - и сравнивать разные понимания именно этих возможностей. А уж кто под эти требования не подходит, и кому повезло -  с Божьей помощью как-нибудь разберемся.  
Если вы будете вдруг оспаривать решение комиссии - что будет являться оспариваемым положением: ваше соответствие требованиям или соответствие требований закону? Ясно, что второе.

Comment: >или все же имеется ввиду три варианта...  
  
Это варианты, которые может сформулировать комиссия?
Ормально их, имхо, много больше.
Юридическое
Экономическое
Специальное
Юридическое либо экономическое
Юридическое либо специальное
Экономическое либо специальное
Юридическое, либо экономическое, либо специальное 
... (под вопросом:)
Юридическое и специальное
Экономическое и специальное...
(Юридическое или экономическое) и специальное 
Юридическое или (экономическое и специальное)...
далее - везде.

Comment: Вы поймите, Закон описывает **опции** для комиссии, а не шаблон для формулировки. 
А было бы шаблоном, то было бы только два варианта:    
включать требование, формулируемое в вашей цитате, или не включать. ТЬогда бы и вопросов не было.

Answer (score 6):

С точки зрения русского языка это одинаково: что Ваш первый вариант, что второй, ведь в паре"юридическое или экономическое" тоже ИЛИ, а не И.Нужно одно из перечисленных образований.

Основное требование к кандидатуре арбитражного управляющего в деле о банкротстве - наличие высшего профессионального образования; дополнительные требования: наличие высшего образования  юридического, или экономического ,или образования по специальности, соответствующей сфере деятельности должника. Имеется в виду, чтобы он был компетентен в сфере деятельности должника, а то будет у него высшее педагогическое образование, а должник - работник сельского хозяйства, он же в этом не разбирается, а юрист, экономист или человек с высшим сельскохозяйственным образованием разберётся.

Comment: Никаких запятых здесь не нужно: пара однородных членов присоединяется к третьему. Для первой пары есть общее слово - образование.

Comment: Почему тогда в другом постановлении правительства пишется: Наличие высшего юридического, или экономического образования, или высшего образования по специальности, соответствующей сфере деятельности должника.

Comment: Учитывая, что разделительные союзы "или" и "либо" синонимы

Comment: Людмила, вы совершенно верно ответили "за русский язык", а дальше пошел разговор слепого с глухим. Вы не так это все понимаете, имхо. 
Во-первых, нет никаких основных и дополнительных требований, все они равнозначны, а во-вторых (и в главных), речь идет о не о требованиях непосредственно к управляющему, а только о списке требований, из которых *может* выбирать конкурсная комиссия для предъявления к нему. Т.е., как я понимаю, *может* вообще не выбрать ни одного, а может выбрать все три. Ну или (как, видимо, понимает Фрекен Бок в одном из своих вариантов) *не может* выбирать вообще.

Comment: behemothus, спасибо за такой развернутый ответ! Дальнейшее обсуждение ни к чему не приведет, к сожалению. А Вы знаете, что есть Методика
проведения антикоррупционной экспертизы  правовых актов 
(пост.Прав. РФ N 96) 
Так вот коррупциогенными факторами являются:
а) наличие завышенных требований к лицу,..установление неопределенных, трудновыполнимых и обременительных требований;
б)...отсутствие четкой регламентации прав граждан и организаций;
в) юридико-лингвистическая неопределенность - употребление неустоявшихся, двусмысленных терминов и категорий оценочного характера.

Вот как-то так(((

Comment: >Дальнейшее обсуждение ни к чему не приведет,  
  
Как скажете. Но я-то как раз думаю, что мы были на пути по крайней мере ко взаимопониманию. 

>Вы знаете, что есть Методика проведения антикоррупционной экспертизы правовых актов  
  
Нет, это не моя область. Но в принципе что-то такое, естественно, должно быть. В стране, где "закон что дышло" её не может не быть. Интересно, сама методика, писаная подобным языком, выдержит экспертизу по этой методике?  
Кстати, а разве конкурсные требования подпадают под категорию "правовых актов"?   
Или вы экспертизу самого закон собрались проводить?  )))

Answer (score 2):

Фрекен Бок, по опыту могу сказать, что у лингвистов, не являющихся специалистами в в конкретных вопросах юридической экспертизы текста, бесполезно спрашивать разрешения спорных трактовок. Как правило все ограничивается общими рассуждениями и ответом, что оба понимания допустимы, что, конечно, никак не устроит юриста. 
Тем не менее рискну дать свое видение. 
Начну с того, что "либо" может употребляться в двух значениях: как синоним "или" или как синоним "исключающему или" (или - или). Это не должно путать, здесь явно первый случай.
Тем не менее, здесь "или" и "либо" - "не совсем" синонимы, хотя и соединяют равновозможные альтернативы. Поэтому и нет запятой. Людмила права, говоря о том, что есть общий член, смысловая структура выглядит примерно так:

Образование:
{одно из двух} или профильное 
!
! 
юридическое или экономическое.

Сравните: "роди мне сына или дочь либо близнецов".
Здесь даже общего слова нет, но знак не нужен, на один "уровень выбора" ставится альтернатива между одним ребенком и близнецами, а между сыном или дочерью - это уже нижний уровень. А когда есть общее слово, такая трактовка представляется не только допустимой, но единственно возможной.

Что же касается вашего примера из другого закона, то, если руководствоваться здравым смыслом, он выглядит не совсем точно сформулированным, ибо в таком виде слово "образование" ну никак не может может относиться ко всем трем перечисляемым возможностям, Скорее всего авторы не владеют подобными семантико-орфографическими тонкостями. Я бы и этот случай написал без запятых, а чтобы избежать двусмысленности, переформулировал наподобие того, как это сделано в вашем исходном варианте. Кстати, может желание избежать подобных коллизий и вызвало к жизни обсуждаемый вариант?

> *Правка к вопросу*Людмила, я не прошу объяснить смысл требований к управляющему, установленные законом о банкротстве. С точки зрения русского языка Вы тоже склоняетесь, что правилен как первый вариант, так и второй. Но нужно разобраться, как все же читать правильно, поскольку это имеет принципиальное значение.Установят дополнительное требование в виде высшего юридического образования, значит человек имеющий экономическое не сможет стать управляющим. А если прочитать закон как имеющий два варианта дополнительных требований: юридическое или экономическое, а 2 вариант, чтобы имел образование по специальности, то человека с высшим экономическим не могут ограничить таким доптребованием.

А вот тут мне, как математику и логику, придется Вас поправить.
Как ни читай этот закон, здесь нет варианта **дополнительных** требований. 
Ваши оба варианта по сути означают одно и то же: *хотя бы одно из трёх*. Никак не *ровно* одно (можно два или три) и никак не "одно и еще одно".

"(Петя или Саша) или Коля", как ни крути, не означает ни "(Петя и Коля) или Саша", ни "Петя или Коля, но ни Саша". Только "(Петя, или Саша, или Коля)".

Если Вы что-то иное подумали, то объясните "на пальцах", как оно такое получилось.

Давайте так. насколько понимаю, речь об этом законе:
http://www.zakonrf.info/zakon-o-bankrotstve/20.2/

Напишите вариант требований, который бы возможным по первому из ваших вариантов, но не по второму (или наоборот), желательно в таком виде:

Требования типа "экономическое образование  - обязательно" допустимо по первому варианту, а по второму нет.

> вариант №1: Высшее юридическое или высшее экономическое или высшее специальное;   вариант №2: Высшее юридическое или высшее экономическое или специальное, не   обязательно высшее

Это да, тут явная двусмысленность, но она не имеет прямого отношения к союзам И или ИЛИ. Тут вопрос в том, относится ли слово высшее ко всем трем "опциям" (альтернативам), к двум или вообще только к первому (а почему нет?).
Строго говоря эту коллизию не разрешит даже лингвоюридичечкая экспертиза, поскольку это вне её компетенции - нет эталона, с которым можно сравнивать. А если по прецеденту, то таки вещи обычно трактуют расширительно (вернее сказать - суживающе), т.е. распростаняют значение определение максимально далеко. Т.е. по факту - речь здесь идет о высшем специальном образовании.

> вариант №3: -выбрать отдельно наличие высшего юридического или экономического образования - либо отдельно наличие профильного образования. И тогда по критериям будет подходить человек имеющий какое либо из 2-х образований (юр или эконом), либо специальное высшее или не обязательно; вариант №4: или подходит человек, имеющий любое из перечисленных образований.

Вот тут я чего-то по-прежнему не понимаю. Разницы в вариантах - уж точно.
Эти требования формулирует ликвидационная комиссия, так? Она *может* сформулировать требования так, как считает нужным.
Либо обязательно любое из трех, либо обязательно одно из двух. Или просто одно конкретное. А то и два (вот насчет двух или трех можно крепко поспорить, но вы, вроде, не об этом?).
Но этот вопрос опять-таки вне сферы непосредственно русского языка и семантики союзов - в особенности.
Давайте все же перейдем на конкретные формулировки.
Еще раз прошу, напишите вариант требований комиссии, которые вы считаете спорным. Пока вы пишете только варианты понимания требований к комиссии - и не одного спорного примера требований самой комиссии.
Ну например:

*Может ли - в соответствии с Законом - комиссия выдвинуть такое требование: 

Кандидат на должность внешнего управляющего (или как его там) должен иметь: 

~специальное образование 

или 

~любое из двух: экономическое или юридическое.*

Тогда хоть понятно будет, о каких вариантах (№3 и №4) вы говорите.
Кстати, вы не находите, что это совершенно то же самое, что "любое из трёх"? Причем, что юридически, что на бытовом уровне?

> Вот я имею высшее экономическое образование. Если понимать закон,например, что могут предъявить ОДНО из трех образований, то предъявив юридическое или специальное, я не подойду. А если возможно предъявить ЛЮБОЕ из трех, я подойду.

Так это комиссия решает, я так понимаю. Вы хотите спросить, имеет ли право комиссия выдвинуть только одно из трех альтернативных (для кандидата) требований, тем самым лишая всякой альтернативы? Думаю, да. По бытовой логике требование "я либо хочу поговорить с одним из твоих родителей либо хочу поговорить ни с кем" лишено всякого смысла. Да его бы и по-другому сформулировали, если бы такая блажь имела место. А если предписать комиссии либо выдвигать требование "юридическое или специальное", либо не выдвигать вообще, то получается как раз тот самый лишенный всякого  смысла случай: "я хочу, чтобы у кандидата было такое-то образование или этакое, либо никакого". 
Нет, полагаю, вопрос должен стоять так: комиссия выдвигает требование о наличии нужного образования или альтернативы из двух или трех. Да иначе и глупо это все. Ну считает комиссия, что в её случае нужен конкретный специалист, или наоборот, юрист/экономист общего профиля. Зачем же вешать на неё условие "может подойти любой из названных"?

Т.е. "или" и "либо" в исходном тексте надо понимать как альтернативу комиссии (выдвигать то или иное требование), а альтернатива для кандидата (это, кстати, один из наиболее общих подходов подобного анализа текста: рассматривать наиболее общую возможность). Поэтому полагаю, комиссия вправе выдвинуть требование о наличии и какого-то конкретного образования.

Но, впрочем, это мнение дилетанта, но документально это вам сам черт не скажет. Опять же это не вопрос не о союзах ))) если это вопрос жизни и смерти попробуйте все-таки обратиться в Гильдию лингвистов-экспертов. Но там надо, во-первых, четко ставить вопрос, во-вторых, долго, в третьих, дорого.

//=====================
У меня от всего этого слегка поехала крыша, наведя на грустные размышления.
Нашм законы пишут люди, в совершенстве овладевшие канцеляритом, общающиеся на нем и думающие, что понимают друг друга. Над пониманием своего творчества не задумываются, а уж о читающих они думают в последнюю очередь...

Хорошо известна байка, что в английском праве можно избежать наказания за двоеженство, доказав, что у тебя не две жены, а три. Можно что-то подобное представить себе в российских реалиях? Да законы словно специально пишутся так, чтобы всегда сохранялась двусмысленность, которая всегда будет трактоваться не в пользу простого смертного...

Comment: "роди мне сына или дочь либо близнецов". - Интересное сравнение!))) Спасибо за отзыв!

Comment: Дополнительные требования в соответствии с Законом  (да, это Закон о банкротстве) можно выдвинуть. Есть в другой статье общие требования, там в перечне есть наличие высшего образования. То есть управляющий может быть по образованию ветеринаром, метеорологом, спортсменом и т.д. Таким образом, какие именно дополнительные требования можно выдвинуть? 
вариант №1: Высшее юридическое или высшее экономическое или высшее специальное;
вариант №2: Высшее юридическое или высшее экономическое или специальное, не обязательно высшее

Comment: вариант №3: -выбрать отдельно наличие высшего юридического или экономического образования
-  либо отдельно наличие профильного образования. 
И  тогда по критериям будет подходить человек имеющий какое либо из 2-х образований (юр или эконом), либо специальное высшее или не обязательно;
вариант №4:  или   подходит человек, имеющий любое из перечисленных образований.

Comment: Фрекен Бок, вы меня совсем запутали. )))
Уже четыре варианта.
Отвечаю в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Вот-вот , я и сама запуталась))) И наше банкротное сообщество тоже, включая реальных законотворцев.

Comment: Давайте так попробуем. Вот я имею высшее экономическое образование. Если понимать закон,например, что могут предъявить ОДНО из трех образований, то предъявив юридическое или специальное, я не подойду. А если возможно предъявить ЛЮБОЕ из трех, я подойду.

Comment: >Давайте так попробуем... 
Так это комиссия решает, нет? отвечаю в тексте.